# Move UIButton above Keyboard when tapped on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard-events

I have 3 text-fields and 2 buttons. When I tap on text-field, keyboard comes up and the 2 buttons are hidden because of the keyboard. Is it possible to move the buttons above the keyboard and when the keyboard resigns the buttons should go back to their initial position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Declare a delegate, assign your textField to the delegate and then 

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    return YES;
}


- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Assign new frame to your view 
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-110,320,460)]; //here taken -20 for example i.e. your view will be scrolled to -20. change its value according to your requirement.

}

-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
}
```

Edit :- Assign width and height to View using [UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is use library, here is the link https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding, all you need to do is take all your textfields and buttons in UIScrollView and assign scrollview class as "TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView" in storyboard.
There will be zero lines of code in view controller class to manage your requirement and wherever you want to do this throughout your app you can similarly.

Comment: I doubt if this is the "best" way to achieve this. It certainly may be the easy way but adding a third party library for such a small task presents its overhead.

Comment: To achieve this one has to add only one class from this library and it hardly has 8 kb size and moreover adding this one class saves lot of  manual coding and time so I feel it is worth using.

Comment: Well, I personally tried it and it's not a drop-in solution. I did what you and the Usage guidelines suggested and I get a crash. I am not spending any time on learning how to integrate a library for something that can be easily achieved natively.

Comment: okay, thats good. When I used the library for the first time it hardly took 15 mins to integrate. Anyways achieving it natively all by yourself is no bad. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can update the View frames/constraints so buttons will get shown to user.

Moreover you can create a toolbar which will be having those buttons in it. You can add toolbar above the keyboard when textfields are focused.

It will be a better user experience.

Comment: i have color and size for the buttoons. Toolbar wont show that. It will show the default ones

Comment: So you need to go with the updating frames/constraints of the textField and buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Better go with scrollview or else adapt the code below for your convenience.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tap:")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        self.txtUserEmail.delegate = self;
        self.txtPassword.delegate = self;

    }

   func tap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.txtUserEmail.resignFirstResponder()
        self.txtPassword.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```