# possible to have a button on the bottom of the screen move up with the ios keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, keyboard

I'm working on a project in xcode and currently have a save button on the bottom of my view. I am wondering if it's possible to have it push up when the keyboard pops up and sit on top of it then when the keyboard goes away it goes back to the bottom of the view. I'm fairly new to xcode and am working on an existing app helping to make some cosmetic changes.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift

Comment: I think it is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909394/move-uibutton-above-keyboard-when-tapped-on-uitextfield

Comment: Linked question is about moving a textfield, not a button, but it's the same idea.