# uitextview add uitoolbar like notes app in top of keyboard with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitoolbar, uikeyboard

I want to add one editor like this photo to my uitextview is that possible to use some thing like this in one apps ( Delegate ) like table or choose deferent font size in top of uikeyboard as uitoolbar [image]

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460754/how-to-add-buttons-above-keyboard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904848/how-to-add-toolbar-above-keyboard

Comment: Yes, of course! You should create a new `UIView` object with desired size. And add this view as `inputAccessoryView` of your `textField`

Comment: @wojcik   I need exactly same toolbar

Comment: Go for, **Bartłomiej Semańczyk** answer in that LINK.

Comment: you will get exactly that

Comment: You u have to customise as per ur need.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom input view or,if you need it, a custom keyboard.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/custom-keyboards/